# How to resend a query with useQuery based on different state?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

So my example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('defaul')
  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery('data', () => fetch(`https://test.com?param=${param}`)

  ....
}
```

For example, I will change param state in someplace and I want to fetch a date with this updated param. I want to resend the API call each time the param state is changing. How can I achieve this?

P.S. Im using [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) lib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Including your param in the `queryKey` in the `useQuery` declaration should automatically refetch the data when the param changes. See modified example below:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('defaul')
  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(['data', param], () => fetch(`https://test.com?param=${param}`)

  ....
}
```

For more details, see [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key).